# sed 'a' (append) doesn't work on OSX, and simply replaces line?

Tags: macos, sed

I'm trying to update a file by adding text to a new line after a matching line.
Following the documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Appending-text-after-a-line-128) I should be able to do this:

```
$ seq 3 | sed '2a hello'
1
2
hello
3
```

However, on Mac OSX, this doesn't work. Firstly, because `'2a hello'` doesn't seem to be interpreted as a valid sed command. Converting this to `"s/2/a hello/"` resolves the sed error, but simply replaces `2` with `a hello`:

```
$ seq 3 | sed "s/2/a hello/"
1
a hello
3
```

Is there some other way to use the append command with Sed on Mac?

## EDIT

In addition to the answer below, here's how you do it when searching for strings.

As an example, if my file was instead:

```
one 
two 
four
```

And I wanted to add 'three' between two and four, I'd do:

```
sed "/two/a\\
four
"
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. As you can see in [the specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), you are missing the backslash and the newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OSX you should use multiline `sed` for this:

```bash
seq 3 | sed '2a\
hello
'
```

**Output:**

```bash
1
2
hello
3
```

PS: This command will work for `gnu sed` as well.

Comment: how would this change if I was searching for a string?
As an example, if I had an input file where instead of 1, 2, 3 it had "one, two, and three", how do I modify this to search for "two"?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, I'll edit this above